# Asp.net mvc upload word file to read bookmark

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, ms-office

I want to upload a word template which has some bookmarks in it i need a code to read the bookmark and replace with the values which are coming from the database on a form so that i can print the word template can anyone tell me how to do it or any example to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is great .net library at http://docx.codeplex.com/ . It is a real good help for creating and manipulating word documents.